# How can I programmatically rebuild the Magento product flat data for a single, specified store view?

Tags: magento, indexing, denormalization

I'm running a multi-store installation of Magento and I've reached the point where my manual     product imports and the subsequent index rebuild is taking too long.  I want to stagger the jobs but need to know how to isolate the rebuilding of the indeces on a per-site basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$indexer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_flat_indexer')
/* @var $indexer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer */

$indexer->rebuild(store_id);
```

Comment: Oh - that simple huh?  :-)  I'm suffering from having to get into the guts of Magento before I understand the basics, so many thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the resource? Shouldn't it be just getModel?

Comment: @Benubird The indexer is a resource model.

Comment: @benmarks there is also a plain model for it, which has a rebuild function as well, which is (from what a quick glance can tell) pretty much a wrapper to the resource build function. So, why is it better to access the resource model directly?

Comment: @Benubird Not better, just [precedent](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/CacheController.php#L264)